# Что делать если разделитель входит в ячейку TextFieldParser

Tags: c#, парсер, csv

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Перерыл множество форумов, ничего не помогает :(

**Исходная ячейка**

```
"текст лялял; лялля текст";
```

**Предполагаемый результат**

текст лялял; лялля текст

Свойству HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes установил тру, из-за того, что есть такие данные

```
" лялялля"ояоолялял"лялялляля";
```

**Предполагаемый результат**

лялялля"ояоолялял"лялялляля

**Парсер**

```
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"tmpShdir/rzp.csv", win1251))
            {
          
                    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                    parser.SetDelimiters(";");
                    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
           
                    while (!parser.EndOfData)
                    {
                        if (lineNumber != 0)
                        { .....
```

**Ошибка**

Разбор строки N c помощью текущих разделителей невозможен.

Comment: 1) попробуйте NuGet пакет CsvHelper, он вроде сейчас самый модный в плане разбора CSV. 2) используйте UTF-8 вместо устаревшей кодировки Windows-1251

Comment: Вопрос следет конкретизировать, привести пример исходных данных и результат, который должен получиться. `" лялялля"ояоолялял"лялялляля"` не выглядит валидной ячейкай CSV.

Comment: Так наоборот же, нужно установить `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false`

Comment: Хм. Из этого: `" лялялля"ояоолялял"лялялляля"` должно получиться одно значение или три? Если последнее, значит в качестве разделителя нужно задать и `;` и `"`.